# How to make smooth fade in as user scrolls in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, animation, web

I would like to know how to make an image fade in as the user scrolls in JS. Is there any code that can do it?

Here is the web template I'm using: [website template](http://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page1/academic-education#shout)

Comment: Did you try to Google "image fade in when scroll"? I'm pretty sure there are tons of articles about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find or write an easing function.

Attach a handler to the DOM `onscroll` event.

The handler should transform the current scroll position to a value suitable for the easing function, then send it to the easing function.

The easing function should transform the supplied value into a `Number` between 0 and 100 and return it.

The handler should then set the opacity of the image to this value.

Another way is to use `onscroll` and when a specific position on the page is scrolled to, apply a class/data attribute to the image so that a CSS opacity transition occurs.

Comment: Like question, like answer! +1